# Homemade butter not softening properly

Tags: butter, dairy

Recently made butter in my stand mixer.  Squeezed it dry and rinsed it before kneading in sea salt.  However, when left out the butter is not softening as store bought butter would to make it spreadable.

So I'm wondering which part of the process might affect this.  Did I over-drain it? Or is the salt keeping it solid at warmer temps? Or something else?

Comment: I'm in the same boat a few minutes in the fridge and my butter is rock hard. Look forward to some good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Over churning is my guess. You want to churn the butter until it starts to setup but no more.

Comment: Can you give details? I have so far only made butter "to show the process" with my kids. (Oh, and this was flagged "low quality".)

Comment: This is probably better as a comment unless more girth is added to this post.